# Freshchat SDK not initialized. Please invoke Freshchat.init() first and invoke showConversations() again

Tags: react-native

I get an error on a native react project. That's even when I have already implemented `Freshchat.init (freshchatConfig)` but still get the error as next:

> Freshchat SDK not initialized. Please invoke Freshchat.init () first and invoke showConversations () again!

I got this error when running on Android and ios is still running normally.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by comment out `implementation 'com.google.firebase: firebase-inappmessaging-display: 19.0.7'` because it conflicts with freshchat library

Comment: Hi, is the only way to make it work by removed firebase in app messaging library? I'm facing the same problem with you but firebase in app messaging is mandatory needed for my app.

Answer (score 0):

I just asked Freshchat Team, and they suggested to implement your own Custom Image Loader class.

Please refer to [doc](https://support.freshchat.com/support/solutions/articles/50000000207-freshchat-android-sdk-integration-steps) 8.2 Custom Image Loader

It worked for us.

Comment: in iOS native, i'm not able to instantiate the Freshchat SDK, need to talk to them on it.

Comment: just send an email to their customer support

Comment: hi bro can you plz give me the email id of their customer support???